# IIS | Block execution of files in directory

Tags: windows, php, iis, windows-server

I am dealing with user uploads via a PHP application.

I want to secure the server so no exploits are available to the user, such as uploading a php shell and executing it.

I have set it so all uploads are moved outside the webroot into a separate folder. 
As an extra security, I have removed all rights except "read" from the IUSR, on the specefic folder.

To take this a step further, I was told to disable script execution on the folder via IIS.

**Is this necessary, given my situation and the things I have already done? 
If yes, how would I achieve this using IIS 8.**

Thanks

Comment: Rather than move, it would be better not to write them to a path within your web root in the first place. Also, if the storage folder is not in web root IIS settings to allow script execution will not apply - did they offer any further explanation and where was this advice from?

Comment: Do you have to allow all files types, if just pictures, you can take the upload and convert them upon upload which help deter possible code being uploaded as a image and then being run.

Comment: Have you already consulted OWASP? https://owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload